# JavaScript toggle not working no error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a dropdown menu on click on .menu-item-2891.Adding class .active will show the menu. Right now it does not do anything on click and shows no error in console.

```js
$(".menu-item-2891").children('.nav-top-link').click(function() {
  $(".menu-item-2891").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
background: Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-2891" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-2891 has-child" aria-expanded="false"><a class="nav-top-link">MEN</a>
  <button class="toggle"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></button>
  <ul class="children">
    <li id="menu-item-9027" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-9027"><a href="#">SHOP BY CATEGORY</a>
      <ul class="nav-sidebar-ul">
        <li id="menu-item-10798" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10798"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/men/">VIEW ALL PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9019" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9019"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/gym-tshirt/">T-SHIRTS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9020" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9020"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/gym-stringers-tanks/">STRINGERS &amp; TANKS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9025" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9025"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/gym-hoodies/">HOODIES</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9023" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9023"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/jogger-pants/">JOGGER PANTS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9024" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9024"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/gym-shorts/">SHORTS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9973" class="label-new menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9973"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/men-gym-leggings/">MEN’S LEGGINGS / TIGHTS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-9028" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-9028"><a href="#">SHOP BY SERIES</a>
      <ul class="nav-sidebar-ul">
        <li id="menu-item-9021" class="label-new menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9021"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/men-new-arrivals/">NEW ARRIVALS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9029" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9029"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/series/ribbed-series/">RIBBED SERIES</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9035"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/series/series-2-0/">SERIES 2.0</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10509" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10509"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/series/seamless/">SEAMLESS SERIES</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9026" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9026"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/sale/">SALE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Where is `.menu-item-289`?

Comment: @Satpal: On first line of menu

Comment: @pedram: Its both id and class.

Comment: and its `menu-item-2891` not `menu-item-289`. Your JS contains `menu-item-289`

Comment: @FahadUddin yeah saw that after the comment

Comment: `.menu-item-289 != .menu-item-2891`

Comment: I removed the typo, still its not working.

Comment: Why you don't click directly `$('.nav-top-link')` ? it works with this

Comment: @pedram: Because many menu items have that class and I want to implement the drop down on just one of them.

Comment: @FahadUddin See your updated post. snippet.

Comment: @pedram: Can you post that as an answer so I can accept? My browser was caching so I couldn't see the changes previously. Thanks for mentioning the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
$(".menu-item-2891").children('.nav-top-link').click(function() {
  $(".menu-item-2891").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
background: Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu-item-2891" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-2891 has-child" aria-expanded="false"><a class="nav-top-link">MEN</a>
  <button class="toggle"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></button>
  <ul class="children">
    <li id="menu-item-9027" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-9027"><a href="#">SHOP BY CATEGORY</a>
      <ul class="nav-sidebar-ul">
        <li id="menu-item-10798" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10798"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/men/">VIEW ALL PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9019" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9019"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/gym-tshirt/">T-SHIRTS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9020" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9020"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/gym-stringers-tanks/">STRINGERS &amp; TANKS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9025" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9025"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/gym-hoodies/">HOODIES</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9023" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9023"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/jogger-pants/">JOGGER PANTS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9024" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9024"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/gym-shorts/">SHORTS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9973" class="label-new menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9973"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/men-gym-leggings/">MEN’S LEGGINGS / TIGHTS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-9028" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-9028"><a href="#">SHOP BY SERIES</a>
      <ul class="nav-sidebar-ul">
        <li id="menu-item-9021" class="label-new menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9021"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/men-new-arrivals/">NEW ARRIVALS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9029" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9029"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/series/ribbed-series/">RIBBED SERIES</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9035"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/series/series-2-0/">SERIES 2.0</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-10509" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10509"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/series/seamless/">SEAMLESS SERIES</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9026" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9026"><a href="https://squatwolf.staging.wpengine.com/product-category/sale/">SALE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding class "active" doesnt make the drop down appear, you are simply adding "active" as one of the classes to your element. You need to define what happens when the element is active.

Try making the default value for the dropdown selections' 
 *opacity: 0;*

and when dropdown is active change it to 1.